# how to build a rule which is based on dotenv variable which was defined previously in same pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm setting a variable in a job in the pipeline and use it in the artifacts / dotenv.
It doesn't seem to work to use the variable as a condition in the rules.
How can I set a env variable and use it in another Job's rule?

Thanks a lot for your thoughts!

```
include:
  - local: '/gitlab/cicd/.gitlab-ci_test.yml'

stages:
  - build
  - test
  
    
build_rule:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /R::/m
  script:
    - echo "Hello World"
    - |
      echo "RUNTESTS=1" > gitlabcicd.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: gitlabcicd.env
```

```
test_always:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - echo "TestEnv" $RUNTESTS 
    # prints TestEnv 1
   
test_sometimes:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $RUNTESTS
    # $RUNTESTS == "1" doesnt work either
  script:
    - echo "Runs only if variable was set"
    # doesnt run, even if it prints above
```

Comment: Where you able to get it to work? I have exactly the same use case and AFAIK, the answer is that you can't do that :'(
Edit: Ok, the answer is "not yet", issue still open as of today: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/235812

Answer (score 2):

As I posted in a comment before, but just so people can find it more easily, the answer is that, unfortunately, right now it is not possible to do that.

There is an issue about it here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/235812

No satisfactory workaround that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Is needed to load the .env file on every job

```
"Set variables":
  stage: preparation
  script:
    - echo version=1.1 > varfile
    - echo foo=bar >> varfile
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - varfile

Dothings:
  stage: run
  script:
    - load varfile
    - echo ${foo}
```

Comment: I want to trigger `Dothings` only, if the variable is set. Thus I have the rule in the job, which shall check the variable before even getting to the script.